# Select Tag, Options_from_collection_for_select determine correct id for selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form:

```
<% tb_form_for [:location] do |f| %>
 <%= f.tb_text_field :name %>
 <%= f.tb_number_field :postal_code %>
 <%= f.tb_text_field :phone %>
 <%= tb_select :region_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Region.all, :id, :name, :region_id)%>
 <% end %>
```

I understand the breakdown for the options from collection for select. Position one is collection, position two is value, position three is text method, and position for is selected. The first three positions work fine it's the selected that I can't quite get to work.

For example if I have a location of Chicago with an id of 4. It has a region of Illinois of 6. When I go to edit the form instead of seeing Illinois I see California (which has an id of 4).

I've tried for the selected:

- :region_id and this shows the first in the collection
- :id and this shows the first in the collection
- params[:id] and this pulls the id of the location and pulls the region that has THAT id
- params[:region_id] and this shows the first in the collection

Am I missing something?

Region has_many locations. Location belongs_to Region. Region controller looks like:

```
class Admin::RegionsController < Admin::ApplicationController
 belongs_to_app :regions
  add_breadcrumb 'Regions', :admin_regions_path
  before_action :load_region, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @regions = Region.ordered.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @regions = @regions.search(params[:search]) if params[:search]
    respond_with @regions
  end

  def show
    respond_with @region
  end

  def new
    @region = Region.new
    respond_with @region
  end

  def create
    operation = Region::Create.run(region_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Region created successfully' if operation.success
    respond_with operation.result, location: admin_regions_path
  end

  def edit
    respond_with @region
  end

  def update
    flash[:notice] = 'Region updated successfully' if @region.update_attributes(region_params)
    respond_with @region, location: admin_regions_path
  end

  def destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'Region deleted successfully' if @region.destroy
    respond_with @region, location: admin_regions_path
  end

  private

  def load_region
    @region = Region.find_by!(id: params[:id])
  end

  def region_params
    params.require(:region).permit(:name, :description, :youtube_url,
  :url_name, :staff_photo, :group_photo,
  location_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Comment: how this is associated?

Comment: I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. Location pulls in the region id so I just need to reference the id on the location. So the answer was actually:

```
<%= tb_select :region_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Region.all, :id, :name, @location.region_id)%>
```